# maven java build errors outside the eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I normally build/generate the java classes file within the eclipse. However, now I need to have the project working on a machine without eclipse, so I build it directly from command line using maven. Then I got the following errors, did I miss anything here? Thanks!

```
Edamame$ mvn java:compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 23.9 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 36.1 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.023 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-09T07:23:05-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'java' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/Edamame/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

---

And here is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edamame.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>EdamameProject</name>
    <url>http://myEdamame.com</url>

    <properties>
        <jdkLevel>1.7</jdkLevel>
        <requiredMavenVersion>[2.1,)</requiredMavenVersion>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdkLevel}</source>
                    <target>${jdkLevel}</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
         :
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        :
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

Also, here is the output of "mvn compile", it succeeded, just doesn't create target/classes folder and its classes.

```
Edamame$ mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myProject 1.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.073 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-09T08:26:12-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change the `<packaging>` value in your pom.xml to something other than "pom" to make Maven run the compile plugin at all. Try "jar".

Then, if you just want to compile the sources, use

```
mvn compile
```

If you want a packaged JAR, call

```
mvn package
```

See [Maven Build Lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) and [Maven POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) for details.

Comment: mvn compile succeed, but it didn't create any target/classes for the Java classes. How to make it create the classes?

Comment: You need to have your source files in any sub-directory of src/main/java relative to your pom.xml. Otherwise Maven won't find them. If your sources are in src/main/java, please post the output of `mvn compile`.

Comment: Please see the "mvn compile" output above. It succeed just no output classes. Thanks!

Comment: My bad. You actually need to change the `<packaging>` value to something other than "pom" to make Maven run the compile plugin at all. Try "jar".

Answer (score 0):

You should just go: mvn compile (or even mvn install or something like that to test it and make everything).